# Android Studio No resource found @drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I have been following the developer tutorial from the official android Udacity course and they have exercises where you work on projects they have uploaded to github.

All of their projects I have worked on so far have gone smoothly. Unfortunately, the latest project (and a lot of projects after this project) have the same dependency errors and soon as I open them. All the errors seem to be looking for a resource in a drawable folder. I realize I don't have a drawable folder under my resources, but I feel this could be a problem due to the fact that I am lacking the correct hidden resource files (if that is possible, i am still new to android development).

Another possibility is that version of android studio and my sdk's are a newer version than the project was originally created with which means the resource calls could be outdated.

I realize that several of the resource calls seem to have to do with the holo theme which has caused me problems in the past.

[image: Errors]

[image: Directories]

Here is a link to some of the resource calls
http://puu.sh/sKafe/d0a2fd7126.png

My compiled and target sdk version is 25
[image: SDK]

Here is the github for the project exercise I am attempting to do
https://github.com/udacity/ud851-Exercises/tree/student/Lesson02-GitHub-Repo-Search/T02.04-Exercise-ConnectingToTheInternet

Comment: i can't see the image very well, you don't have the drawables folder? you can add it, go to de res folder and create  a new folder and name it drawable, then you can add the drawables to the folder

Comment: You need the Holo resources that are in SDK 14+ (I think). That's what the errors are telling you. They aren't "hidden", then are just not part of the API you are using

Comment: I am using sdk 25, which is 14+. Unless the holo resources got removed in later sdk's shouldn't I still have the holo resources I need. Are the holo resources part of the normal api packages, or do I download them seperately somewhere else http://puu.sh/sKaB1/878b25aeb8.png

Comment: can you click on the errors and find out where do you need these drawables in your java code

Comment: Here are some screenshots of some of the locations where it is pointing to the missing resources. http://puu.sh/sKjME/0bf6f96c51.png     http://puu.sh/sKjNc/f808ccbf59.png     http://puu.sh/sKjNz/eed724a9e1.png     http://puu.sh/sKjO0/74eb6cc2a3.png     http://puu.sh/sKjOE/8dd7310737.png

Comment: Can't you contact the instructors / post a github issue?

Comment: Also, I just cloned that repo, and can build the project just fine, so I'm guessing there is something missing within your SDK setup

Comment: Follow up comment to that - Are you making Android TV and Wear Apps? You do not need every single System Image installed. Just pick the platforms you are developing for. (Typically just the intel images)

Comment: Yeah, I can try that. Weirdly enough, it seems that only part 2-4 and 2-5 have this problem. I recently tested part 2-6 and it seems to work fine. What doesn't make much sense because each consecutive part is basically the same project that is being updated with small changes. Between parts 2-3 to 2-4 and parts 2-5 to 2-6 there were only small changes that should not affect resource dependencies at all like the adding of simple methods or internet permissions. But, for some reason the project broke starting on 2.4 and worked correctly again on part 2.6.

Comment: At this point, I'm just curious on what caused the project to break, so I can fix it if it happens in the future.

Comment: No, I'm only developing for android phone/tablet at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was causing the problem. I re-cloned the GitHub, but this time I ran the project from the downloads folder and it worked fine. I found out that the first time i downloaded the zip folder with the project, I unzipped it and then moved it to another directory where I keep my android projects. When I moved the project folder to the new directory, the file directory names became longer and some particular files names became longer than the character limit for the windows file naming system. I was then prompted to skip those particular files which I must have selected yes, which caused the missing dependency issues.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have the drawable directory,create one

right click on the res directory,

res -> New -> Directory

[image]

Enter the Directory Name as drawable -> ok

[image]

add the drawble file in that.thats all.

Comment: Add what drawable? You can't just "insert" all the holo resources.

Comment: It seems the errors have to do with the fact I am missing dependencies for the holo theme and some other small dependencies which might be part of an older api. This wouldn't help with that.

Comment: the github project has only two java file, one layout xml file and a menu fie.

Comment: create a new project and add these files

Comment: and the gitHub link you provided has no drawable folder.

Comment: @BLin Try to build the Github project linked in the question, please. No files need added. Your solution here isn't correct.